# Getting text search relevance scores out of ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb

Does ArangoDB provide a way of getting the underlying scores out of text search queries, either through AQL queries against fulltext index or via a custom search view?

One use case for this is to colour search results based on their relevance in a UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR doc IN myView 
    SEARCH PHRASE(doc.abstract,"fulltext search","text_en") 
        OR PHRASE(doc.text,"fulltext search","text_en")
    SORT BM25(doc)
    LIMIT 10
    RETURN { id: doc._key, title: doc.title, score: bm25(doc) }
```

This would return the top 10 results with the BM25 score (TF/IDF is supported as well) that you can use for highlighting individual records.

I think the support of scores in return values was introduced just recently. I am currently testing 3.5.